Finding matching duplicates in 2 separate columns
I have a table with "email", "fruits", and ID as the columns.
I want a list of all records with the matching (email + fruit). Records with the same email are being compared with each other (table will have various emails present in it) and should pull records that have "matching" fruit values. I say matching because "banana" and "apple;banana" have the word "banana" overlapping.
In the below table, all 3 records for john@gmail.com would be marked as duplicates. The fruit value for record 1 overlaps with fruit value for record 3. I want all 3 records to be shown in my query result.



email
fruit
ID




john@gmail.com
apple
123


john@gmail.com
banana
345


john@gmail.com
apple;banana
678


smith@gmail.com
banana
901



Adding another example of records I want included in my query:



email
fruit
ID




john@gmail.com
apple
123


john@gmail.com
banana
345



The below example would NOT be considered as duplicates since each record for this email  has a unique fruit value. I do not want these 2 records to be shown in my query result. This is the edge case I am having issues with.



email
fruit
ID




smith@gmail.com
apple
902


smith@gmail.com
banana
901



Sample Table



email
fruit
ID




john@gmail.com
apple
123


john@gmail.com
banana
345


john@gmail.com
apple;banana
678


smith@gmail.com
banana
901


smith@gmail.com
apple
902



This is my code so far, but it is not satisfying the edge case:
select a.primaryemail, a.fruits

from default.customerdetails a

    inner join (select sub.primaryemail, count(sub.primaryemail)
    from default.customerdetails sub


    group by sub.primaryemail, sub.fruits
    having count(*) >1 ) sub on a.primaryemail=sub.primaryemail


While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Please don't tag conflicting products, just tag the one you are really using.

Seems like you need to fix your design and then put a unique constraint in place. What we have is an XY Problem.

This is my code so far, but it is not satisfying the edge case:
select a.primaryemail, a.fruits
from default.customerdetails a

    inner join (select sub.primaryemail, count(sub.primaryemail)
    from default.customerdetails sub


    group by sub.default.customerdetails, sub.fruits
    having count(*) >1 ) sub on a.primaryemail=sub.primaryemail


You need to use the [edit] feature for that information, @afraah .

It's throwing an error when I try adding this code, even after using the code button and trying to indent. When you mention design, do you mean the table? The table and column style has been decided by my team.

I copied your code up into your question, but the code needs work. Your samp,le data has column names that differ from your query, and the column reference in group by sub.default.customerdetails does not appear valid. Please edit and fix. Also, check your sample data and expected results. Why would your second set of data be included, while the third sample is not. It would be best to include a single combined sample data set and matching expected results that demonstrates expected behavior across multiple cases. A clearer definition of the intended logic would also be helpful.

@TN - You guys are right. I tried making the problem as abstract as possible to make it easier to solve and for data confidentiality purposes but ended up removing an important column - which is the ID column. I'm not sure if this helps understanding the problem better or if it just makes it more difficult.
I have also added a sample table now as you guys have suggested.

@afraah - You state that ID is an "important" column, but have not described how it is involved in the desired logic. It looks like an uninvolved column to me. You also have not yet addressed the other issues mentioned above. Please go back and read the above comments again, provide the requested information, and fix your examples.

String delimited lists is an anti-pattern in SQL. Why is it the chosen design, and can it be changed?

@afraah I have provided the code. please try and check the results.

You can use below query for your problem statement.
select email,fruit,Id from customerdetails
where ID in (select distinct(explode(sub2.Dup_fruit_IDs))
from
(select collect_set(sub1.ID) as Dup_fruit_IDs
from
(SELECT email, explode(split(fruit, ';')) AS sfruit, ID FROM customerdetails) sub1
GROUP BY email,sfruit
having count(*)>1) sub2)


Here, first splitting it up and exploded
SELECT email, explode(split(fruit, ';')) AS sfruit, ID FROM customerdetails

then done collect_set on group by data, next using  having count(*)>1 getting all of the ids having duplicate.
select distinct(explode(sub2.Dup_fruit_IDs))
from
(select collect_set(sub1.ID) as Dup_fruit_IDs
from
(SELECT email, explode(split(fruit, ';')) AS sfruit, ID FROM customerdetails) sub1
GROUP BY email,sfruit
having count(*)>1) sub2

Using above result ids to get the records of duplicate.
Output:


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I was just showing the code works with successful output. Next I won't upload

Thank you for sharing this solution Jayashankar, and sorry for the late response! I just tried this query, but unfortunately I am seeing a memory error (since I have a huge number of records on my table). On further evaluation, it looks like it is due to the collect_set() function. I'm not sure if there is an alternate method that can be used....

What is the exact error. Please upload the screen shot of it.
